# Python Return True or False

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't believe I set this up right... because no matter what numbers I fill in for foo() it always seems to return "True". What am I doing wrong??

```
# Complete the following function.
# Returns True if x * y / z is odd, False otherwise.

def foo(x, y, z):
    answer = True
    product = (x * y) / z
    if (product%2) == 0:
        answer = False
    return answer

print(foo(1,2,3))
```

Comment: let me ask you what you would enter to return False

Comment: Yes it is correct in my actual program, but I did not set it up right posting in here.

Comment: [Well, it works fine](http://labs.codecademy.com/CdIh#:workspace)

Comment: I have tried several different variables and they all return true... what da f..

Comment: you guys using python3.4?

Comment: @vks 2.x vs 3.x does, because of integer division...

Comment: @vks, Python 3 does not do integer division unless you use `//`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that the OP is confused because `Python 3` does not do integer division when the `/` operator is used.

Consider the following modification to the OP's program, so we can get better insight into this.

```
def foo(x, y, z):
    answer = True
    product = (x * y) / z
    print(product)
    if (product%2) == 0:
        answer = False
    return answer

print(foo(1,2,3))
print(foo(2,2,2))
```

Output of Python 2:

```
python TrueMe.py 
0
False
2
False
```

Output of Python 3:

```
python3 TrueMe.py 
0.6666666666666666
True
2.0
False
```

Needless to say, the inputs `2,2,2` does actually cause a return value of `False` to be produced.

If you want to get integer division in Python3, you must use `//` instead of `/`.

Comment: That is a news to me!!!!!!!!!Thanx a lot

Comment: Ugh... these different versions are killing me...(frustrated)

Comment: @MarcusBurkhart, Take a look at [this document](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/) which discusses this, and [this document](https://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html) which discusses other differences.

Comment: @merlin2011 thanks man. very helpful and much appreciated for the quick responses.